# Basic Python Multiprocessing Example Doesn't Spawn Process

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm having an issue getting started using Python's Multiprocessing library.

When I run one of the most basic examples (shown below) I don't get anything to print to the console:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I was expecting to see `hello bob` but instead it hung for a moment before eventually finishing and printing nothing to the console.

Here's the command that is run by VSCode when I hit F5. My code (shown above) is in a file at `QueueTrigger1/__init__.py`

[image]

I'm running python ver 3.9.5 (here's the printout from just running python)

[image]

Any assistance on why my Multiprocess isn't spawning would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Code works fine for me.  Are you sure that \_\_init\_\_.py contains nothing but what is shown?

Comment: oh man, @DanielWalker that was it. The file i'm playing with has a lot of code in it so I'd placed the above code at the top of the file and placed an `exit()` at the bottom of it so none of the other code would run... I'm new to python (coming from C/C++/C#/Javascript) and so figured the exit after my code would just keep the below code from running.... Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah.  I think what happened is, in the child process, Python first re-imported your module before it ran `f`.  It saw the definition of `f`, skipped over the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and then executed the `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'd placed this code at the top of a longer .py file full of code.

I'd put an `exit()` at the bottom of my testing code thinking it would simply hide the other code in the rest of my .py file.

This `exit()` statment ended up making the child process not run correctly. Thanks for @DanielWalker for the tip.

The solution was to remove the exit statement and cleanup the rest of the file.